# How do I get the windows + print to save a screenshot again in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, screenshot

I have a computer with Windows 11 installed.

I would like to use the Windows + Print Screen key combination to save a screenshot to the Pictures folder of the current user, just like I used to do in Windows 10.
 When I press the keys, the screen briefly dims as if a screenshot was taken, but no file is saved anywhere.
 How can I reactivate this function?

Comment: You mention the *Pictures folder*, but did you check in the *Pictures\Screenshots* subdirectory?

Comment: @YisroelTech Yes, and also the one in Onedrive\Pictures\Screenshots
I just tried to add a new user without Microsoft Account, and there it works as expected.

Comment: Can you check in Windows Explorer by Recent right after doing the Win Key + Print Screen and see if it has the screenshot there as the last file, and if so what's location it shows? An assumption would be that you have installed some "alternative" screenshot utility (like ShareX, Greenshot, or the like and that application is capturing the screenshot.

Comment: @YisroelTech Thank You! Thanks to your hint for looking to the Recent Files I found the registry key that was messed up

Comment: Great. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) adding the details of what it was and how you corrected it.

Comment: @YisroelTech I just added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @YisroelTech, who pointed me in the right direction, I was finally able to solve the problem. It turned out that the screenshot was being created in the wrong location. Upon searching the registry for this path, I discovered that the issue was within:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

I had to change the value of:
`{B7BEDE81-DF94-4682-A7D8-57A52620B86F}` to `%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Screenshots`

After restarting Windows, it started working properly again.

Note: There is also a 
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

Comment: it would be nice if you comment about relation of the last registry path, `HKLM` to the first registry path, `HKCU`. Then can you please tell what was the value in `{B7BEDE81-DF94-4682-A7D8-57A52620B86F}` before you changed it?

Answer (score -1):

> How can I reactivate this function?

<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> has always created a screenshot of your desktop `%UserProfile%\Pictures\Screenshots`.

> Depending on your hardware, you may use the Windows Logo Key + PrtScn button as a shortcut for print screen. If your device does not have the PrtScn button, you may use Fn + Windows logo key  + Space Bar to take a screenshot, which can then be printed.

[Keyboard shortcut for print screen](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcut-for-print-screen-601210c0-b3a9-7b58-bc40-bae4dcf5f108)

This behavior has remained unchanged since at least Windows 10 21H2 and extends to all applicable versions (Windows 11 21H1+, Windows 10 22H2+)